# K-Means clustering Hyperparameter Tuning

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to perform hyperparameter tuning for Spatio-Temporal K-Means clustering by using it in a pipeline with a Decision Tree classifier. The idea is to use K-Means clustering algorithm to generate cluster-distance space matrix and clustered labels which will be then passed to Decision Tree classifier. For hyperparameter tuning, just use parameters for K-Means algorithm.

I am using Python 3.8 and sklearn 0.22.

The data I am interested is having 3 columns/attributes: 'time', 'x' and 'y' (x and y are spatial coordinates).

The code is:

```
class ST_KMeans(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
# class ST_KMeans():
    """
    Note that K-means clustering algorithm is designed for Euclidean distances.
    It may stop converging with other distances, when the mean is no longer a
    best estimation for the cluster 'center'.

    The 'mean' minimizes squared differences (or, squared Euclidean distance).
    If you want a different distance function, you need to replace the mean with
    an appropriate center estimation.


    Parameters:

    k:  number of clusters

    eps1 : float, default=0.5
        The spatial density threshold (maximum spatial distance) between 
        two points to be considered related.

    eps2 : float, default=10
        The temporal threshold (maximum temporal distance) between two 
        points to be considered related.

    metric : string default='euclidean'
        The used distance metric - more options are
        ‘braycurtis’, ‘canberra’, ‘chebyshev’, ‘cityblock’, ‘correlation’,
        ‘cosine’, ‘dice’, ‘euclidean’, ‘hamming’, ‘jaccard’, ‘jensenshannon’,
        ‘kulsinski’, ‘mahalanobis’, ‘matching’, ‘rogerstanimoto’, ‘sqeuclidean’,
        ‘russellrao’, ‘seuclidean’, ‘sokalmichener’, ‘sokalsneath’, ‘yule’.

    n_jobs : int or None, default=-1
        The number of processes to start; -1 means use all processors (BE AWARE)


    Attributes:

    labels : array, shape = [n_samples]
        Cluster labels for the data - noise is defined as -1
    """

    def __init__(self, k, eps1 = 0.5, eps2 = 10, metric = 'euclidean', n_jobs = 1):
        self.k = k
        self.eps1 = eps1
        self.eps2 = eps2
        # self.min_samples = min_samples
        self.metric = metric
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs


    def fit(self, X):
        """
        Apply the ST K-Means algorithm 

        X : 2D numpy array. The first attribute of the array should be time attribute
            as float. The following positions in the array are treated as spatial
            coordinates.
            The structure should look like this [[time_step1, x, y], [time_step2, x, y]..]

            For example 2D dataset:
            array([[0,0.45,0.43],
            [0,0.54,0.34],...])


        Returns:

        self
        """

        # check if input is correct
        X = check_array(X)

        # type(X)
        # numpy.ndarray

        # Check arguments for DBSCAN algo-
        if not self.eps1 > 0.0 or not self.eps2 > 0.0:
            raise ValueError('eps1, eps2, minPts must be positive')

        # Get dimensions of 'X'-
        # n - number of rows
        # m - number of attributes/columns-
        n, m = X.shape


        # Compute sqaured form Euclidean Distance Matrix for 'time' and spatial attributes-
        time_dist = squareform(pdist(X[:, 0].reshape(n, 1), metric = self.metric))
        euc_dist = squareform(pdist(X[:, 1:], metric = self.metric))

        '''
        Filter the euclidean distance matrix using time distance matrix. The code snippet gets all the
        indices of the 'time_dist' matrix in which the time distance is smaller than 'eps2'.
        Afterward, for the same indices in the euclidean distance matrix the 'eps1' is doubled which results
        in the fact that the indices are not considered during clustering - as they are bigger than 'eps1'.
        '''
        # filter 'euc_dist' matrix using 'time_dist' matrix-
        dist = np.where(time_dist <= self.eps2, euc_dist, 2 * self.eps1)


        # Initialize K-Means clustering model-
        kmeans_clust_model = KMeans(
            n_clusters = self.k, init = 'k-means++',
            n_init = 10, max_iter = 300,
            precompute_distances = 'auto', algorithm = 'auto')

        # Train model-
        kmeans_clust_model.fit(dist)


        self.labels = kmeans_clust_model.labels_
        self.X_transformed = kmeans_clust_model.fit_transform(X)

        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        pass


# Initialize ST-K-Means object-
st_kmeans_algo = ST_KMeans(
    k = 5, eps1=0.6,
    eps2=9, metric='euclidean',
    n_jobs=1
    )

# Train on a chunk of dataset-
st_kmeans_algo.fit(data.loc[:500, ['time', 'x', 'y']])

# Get clustered data points labels-
kmeans_labels = st_kmeans_algo.labels

kmeans_labels.shape
# (501,)


# Get labels for points clustered using trained model-
kmeans_transformed = st_kmeans_algo.X_transformed

kmeans_transformed.shape
# (501, 5)


dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()

dtc.fit(kmeans_transformed, kmeans_labels)

y_pred = dtc.predict(kmeans_transformed)

# Get model performance metrics-
accuracy = accuracy_score(kmeans_labels, y_pred)
precision = precision_score(kmeans_labels, y_pred, average='macro')
recall = recall_score(kmeans_labels, y_pred, average='macro')

print("\nDT model metrics are:")
print("accuracy = {0:.4f}, precision = {1:.4f} & recall = {2:.4f}\n".format(
    accuracy, precision, recall
    ))

# DT model metrics are:
# accuracy = 1.0000, precision = 1.0000 & recall = 1.0000
```

However, when I try to perform hyper-paramter tuning using sklearn's pipeline:

```
# Hyper-parameter Tuning:
# Define steps of pipeline-
pipeline_steps = [
    ('st_kmeans_algo' ,ST_KMeans(k = 5, eps1=0.6, eps2=9, metric='euclidean', n_jobs=1)),
    ('dtc', DecisionTreeClassifier())
    ]

# Instantiate a pipeline-
pipeline = Pipeline(pipeline_steps)

# Train pipeline-
pipeline.fit(kmeans_transformed, kmeans_labels)
```

It gives me the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         8 
>         9 # Train pipeline-
>   ---> 10 pipeline.fit(kmeans_transformed, kmeans_labels)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self,
>   X, y, **fit_params)
>       348             This estimator
>       349         """
>   --> 350         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
>       351         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
>       352                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self,
>   X, y, **fit_params)
>       309                 cloned_transformer = clone(transformer)
>       310             # Fit or load from cache the current transformer
>   --> 311             X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
>       312                 cloned_transformer, X, y, None,
>       313                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/memory.py in
>   **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       353 
>       354     def **call**(self, *args, **kwargs):
>   --> 355         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
>       356 
>       357     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in
>   _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
>       726     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
>       727         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
>   --> 728             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
>       729         else:
>       730             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in
>   fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
>       572         else:
>       573             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
>   --> 574             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
>       575 
>       576
>
> TypeError: fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 0):

The fit method in your `ST_KMeans` takes in only `X` as input but in this line:

```
pipeline.fit(kmeans_transformed, kmeans_labels)
```

you pass both `X` and `Y` as input to your pipeline which tries to call the `fit` method of the first stage of your pipeline i.e. `ST_KKeans` with these two arguments resulting in this error. In order to overcome this just add a dummy parameter `y` to the fit method of your `ST_KMeans` objects as shown below:

```
def fit(self, X, Y):
```

The additional parameter `Y` is not used anywhere inside the method it just maintains the consistency.

Comment: I changed fit(self, X, Y) method and when I run "pipeline.fit(kmeans_transformed, kmeans_labels)" call, it gives me the error: "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=nan.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Comment: can you print out the shapes of `kmeans_transformed` and `kmeans_labels` ?

Comment: kmeans_transformed.shape, kmeans_labels.shape                           
# ((501, 5), (501,))

Comment: Can you provide us an example for reproducing the error?